# Find for which $\alpha >0$ this function is in $L^2(\mathbb{R^2})$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces, polar-coordinates

For which values of a real parameter $\alpha >0$, the function $$\frac{1}{|x|^{\alpha} + |y|^{\alpha} +1}$$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R^2})$?

I am pretty sure this involves using polar coordinates (for example it works for the case $\alpha =2$), but all my attempts turned out to be very messy. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: due to symmetry, it's enough to consider the integral only in the first quarter. Moreover, it is enough to consider the area $x^\alpha+y^\alpha\geq1$. Make a replacement $x=r^\frac{2}{\alpha}\cos^\frac{2}{\alpha}\varphi$, $y=r^\frac{2}{\alpha}\sin^\frac{2}{\alpha}\varphi$

Comment: I may have made a mess, but is the Jacobian equal to $\frac{4}{\alpha^2}r^{\frac{4}{\alpha}-1}cos^{\frac{2}{\alpha} -1}\phi sin^{\frac{2}{\alpha} -1} \phi (cos\phi + sin\phi)$ ?

Comment: In brackets should be $\sin^2\varphi+\cos^2\varphi$, i.e. $1$.

Comment: Right. Is the answer for $\alpha > 1$?

Comment: Yes, the answer is $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Sorry, one last question: why is it sufficient to consider the area $x^\alpha+y^\alpha\geq1$ ?

Comment: Because for $x^\alpha+y^\alpha\leq1$ the integral has no singularities.

Comment: Isn't it for $|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha\geq1$ that the denominator could diverge? Why are we omitting the modules?